# Android Fragment giving "Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a basic fragment in and activity and it is throwing an error:

Here are my classes:

fragment class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout._fragment_dds_image, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

}

My Fragment XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0000FF"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

My activity that is trying to display the fragment:

```
public class DDSViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ddsview);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ddsview, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

The XML file for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="dds.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When i run this, it gives em the following error:

Unable to start activty ComponentInfo{com.example.electronicmenu/dds.DDSViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: binary xml file line #10: Error inflating class fragment.

[link to full stack trace:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxtywgav3gbapm6/Error%20to%20Stack%20Trace.txt)

Comment: Show the full stack trace from logcat

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxtywgav3gbapm6/Error%20to%20Stack%20Trace.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified name of your fragment class, e.g. `com.example.myapp.dds.MyFragment`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.dds.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: How do i find my exact fully qualified name?

i tried typing it my self but it gave same error

Comment: It's your fragment class name including the package.

Comment: Still wont work.

I even moved MyFragment to the default package. and then changed teh xml to: ` android:name="com.example.electronicmenu.MyFragment"`

Comment: What is the very first line of your Fragment class' .java file, above all the import statements? should say `package` followed by the package name. So the fully qualified name is `package_name.MyFragment`

Comment: Ok the name is definitely correct now. And im still getting the same error ?

Comment: Does your fragment have any constructors? It must have a no-arg constructor, e.g. `public MyFragment() { ... }`

Comment: Fragment has what is displayed int he post. I didnt leave anything out. So must i Add and empty constructor?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34731/discussion-between-zapnologica-and-karakuri)